# Get a tag with beautifoulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, tags

I want to get a specific part of a tag with beautifulsoup but I can't.
The tag is:

```
<a class="grey-dark" href="/projects/perry/grace-jones-does-not-give-a-f-t-shirt-limited-edition-0/comments?cursor=4#comment-3"><data class="Comment3" data-format="distance_date" data-value="&quot;2009-04-21T15:29:45-04:00&quot;" itemprop="Comment[created_at]">on April 21, 2009</data></a>
```

while the part that I want is only`2009-04-21`. How can I do it using bs4?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very skilled with with regex but you can try to do somenthing like:

```
import re
[...]

html = '<a class="grey-dark" href="/projects/perry/grace-jones-does-not-give-a-f-t-shirt-limited-edition-0/comments?cursor=4#comment-3"><data class="Comment3" data-format="distance_date" data-value="&quot;2009-04-21T15:29:45-04:00&quot;" itemprop="Comment[created_at]">on April 21, 2009</data></a>'
m = re.search('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', html)
if m:
    print m.group(0)
```

This will print any string with 9999-99-99 format. It's important to say that, this regex does not restrict month to 1-12 and days from 1 to 31.

Also, you can use the shorthand regex `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

a = '''<a class="grey-dark" href="/projects/perry/grace-jones-does-not-give-a-f-t-shirt-limited-edition-0/comments?cursor=4#comment-3"><data class="Comment3" data-format="distance_date" data-value="&quot;2009-04-21T15:29:45-04:00&quot;" itemprop="Comment[created_at]">on April 21, 2009</data></a>
'''

soup = bs(a, 'lxml')

print(soup.data['data-value'])
```

The last line is the only important one, .data is the  tag or we can use `soup.find('data')` and we're using the key of the attribute to extract the data needed. 
Like the StackOverFlower above me mentioned you can also use `re` or regex but it's slow and you have to have some previous knowledge of it to understand how it work even tho he explained it really well. Hopefully that answers your question.

So that's the proper way of doing it using `BeautifulSoup` like you asked for not using `re`.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a go:

```
html_content='''
<a class="grey-dark" href="/projects/perry/grace-jones-does-not-give-a-f-t-shirt-limited-edition-0/comments?cursor=4#comment-3">
<data class="Comment3" data-format="distance_date" data-value="&quot;2009-04-21T15:29:45-04:00&quot;" itemprop="Comment[created_at]">on April 21, 2009</data></a>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")
item = soup.select(".Comment3")[0]['data-value'].split("T")[0]
print(item.replace('"',''))
```

Result:

```
2009-04-21
```